# Echoing something out on a specific date every year

Tags: php

So I'm trying to make a message appear on one specific date of the year.

My code now:

```
<?php 
$year = date("Y");

if(checkdate(5, 22, $year) === TRUE) {
echo '<b>something</b>';
}else {
echo '';
}

?>
```

But the message appears howsoever, no matter the date.

Hope you can help me,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to use checkdate, this is an alternative.

```
<?php
if (date('Y-m-d') == date('Y').'-05-22') {
    echo '<b>something</b>';
}    else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

Comment: @MrBlackDrag0nfly I fixed a typo for him. Try it now

Comment: actually you could also just do `if (date('md') == '0522') {`

Comment: @nl-x Thanks for fixing. :-D Yes, that's doable, but OP had the year, so I kept it, too.

Comment: I just got onto something, we are checking the servers date aren't we?

Comment: Yes, that's the date the server knows. :-D

Comment: And if i set a default timezone like date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
It will take that one?

Comment: That's what I see in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: I want to thank you guy's! You have really helped me!

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation [checkdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) only validates dates, it doesn't compare them against the current date.

> Returns TRUE if the date given is valid; otherwise returns FALSE.

Use something similar to the code you already have to check the date

```
if( date("n j") == "5 22")
{
    echo '<b>something</b>';
}
```